# Как вывести значение class элемента <path> в <svg>?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, raphael

Встала задача сравнить значение атрибута `class` со значением другого атрибута. Не получается получить значение - выводит `[object SVGAnimatedString]`:

```
<svg height="485.833" version="1.1" width="545.333" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
        <path fill="green" stroke="#575756" d="M303.666,68.333L316.666,68.333L316.666,121.333L419.666,121.333L419.666,134.333L478.666,134.333L478.666,121.333L542.666,121.333L542.666,2.333L303.666,2.333Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-miterlimit: 10; stroke-opacity: 1;" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-opacity="1" class="201"></path>
        <svg>
```

Выборку произвожу кодом:

```
var countrys = $('path[class]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('class');
});
```

Comment: `<svg height="485.833" version="1.1" width="545.333" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#575756" d="M69.666,344.333L69.666,483.333L183.666,483.333L183.666,302.333L107.666,302.333L107.666,344.333Z" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-opacity="1" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-miterlimit: 10; stroke-opacity: 1;" class="219"></path></svg>`

Comment: Ну возьмите так: var a = $path.prop('className').baseVal;

Comment: Не получилось. Нужно выбрать все значения атрибута class тегов path и получить массив со значениями.

Comment: В [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbdnytov/) выводит `201` без проблем. А если сделать тег `desc` самозакрывающимся, равно как и заменить второй `<svg>` в вопросе на `</svg>`, то даже что-то отрисовывается.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sonitahefu/edit?html,js вот, ваш код работает, у вас не получается произвести сравнение или что?